# how to identify errors in manifest file

Tags: html

I am making the manifest file work for my web page but it is not working when turn of internate and open web page on ipad it says connect to internet.how to solve this issue i have given all the resources used in web page in the manifest file but still it is not working

Below is My Manifest File

```
CACHE MANIFEST
CACHE:
index.html
brd_icon.png
newstyle_tester.css
draxxin.pdf
exede.pdf
js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js
js/script.js
js/jquery.queryloader2.js

image/startbutton.png
image/mockup_splash_1.png
image/testing_file_3.png
image/overview.gif
image/strategy.gif
image/draxxin.gif
image/excede.gif
image/reference.gif
image/results.gif
image/seperator.png
image/overview_active.png
image/strategy_active.png
image/draxxin_active.png
image/excede_active.png
image/result_active.png
image/references_active.png
image/pageone_image.png
image/whiteslide.png
image/option.png
image/option_1.png
image/pagetwo_graph_one.png
image/pagetwo_graph_two_4.png
image/optiononeone.png
image/optiononetwo.png
image/optiontwofirst.png
image/optiontwosecond.png
image/backward.png
image/forward.png
image/button_7days.png
image/button_14days.png
image/close.png
image/popup_page_1.png
image/popup_1_page_2.png
image/popup_2_page_2.png
image/popup_page_3.png
image/popup_page_4.png
image/popup_1_page_5.png
image/popup_2_page_5.png
image/popup_3_page_5.png
image/popup_4_page_5.png
image/smallicon_1.png
image/smallicon_2.png
image/bg_img_lightbox.png
image/tag.png
image/result_graphic_1.png
image/result_graphic_2.png
image/result_graphic_3.png
image/graph1.png
image/graph2.png
image/graph3a.png
image/graph4.png
image/graph5.png
image/graph_one.png
image/graph_three.png
image/bottle_1.png
image/bottle_2.png
image/arrow_1.png
```

Comment: Please post your manifest file

Comment: @robertc I have posted manifest file

Comment: OK, two more questions: Do all those files exist on your server?  How large are those PDF files?

Comment: all these exits pdf or of just one page only

Comment: That's the two most obvious potential issues out of the way then, it's possible the issue is not with the manifest file itself but with something else like your server configuration.  Is your site online?  Can you post a link?

Comment: my site is online i can post link if you want

Comment: @robertc i have poste my link http://celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you've not configured the content type header correctly on your server.  Here's the response to the HTTP request for cache.manifest:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 08 May 2012 09:33:41 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Tue, 08 May 2012 05:07:32 GMT
Etag: "733106-652-4bf7f5d3692a8"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1618
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/plain
```

See that last line?  It should be `text/cache-manifest`.  Change the content type in your server configuration.  For Apache you can add this line to the server config or in an .htaccess file:

```
AddType text/cache-manifest            appcache manifest
```

Comment: mean i may add AddType text/cache-manifest appcache manifest in .htaccess file

Comment: how to  check what response is coming

Comment: @user1374388 If you're in Firefox hit Ctrl+Shift+K, in Chrome use the web inspector.

Comment: yes i have fixed this but again my offline is not working on ipad it is not saving files in cache when you see from ipad device advanced settings

Comment: @user1374388 Possibly the iPad has the old request cached - try clearing the cache in settings